# Embed MS SQL query using results from first query as parameter for second query

Tags: sql-server-2014

I am working with some census data and I need to embed a query and use the results from the first query as criteria for a separate query.

Here is what I have so far.

First Query:

```
SELECT SUMLEV, STATE, COUNTY, PLACE, COUSUB, CONCIT, PRIMGEO_FLAG, FUNCSTAT, NAME, STNAME, CENSUS2010POP, ESTIMATESBASE2010, POPESTIMATE2010, 
                  POPESTIMATE2011, POPESTIMATE2012, POPESTIMATE2013, POPESTIMATE2014
FROM     [SUB-EST2014_ALL]
WHERE  (SUMLEV = '50') AND (CENSUS2010POP > 1000000) AND
                  (CENSUS2010POP < 100000000)
```

One result from this query is:

50  4   13  0   0   0   0   A   Maricopa County Arizona 3817117 3817357 3823609 3870076 3942868 4013164 4087191

The second and third data points in this result, '4' & '13', are what I need for my second query.

That query is:

```
SELECT SUMLEV, STATE, COUNTY, PLACE, COUSUB, CONCIT, PRIMGEO_FLAG, FUNCSTAT, NAME, STNAME, CENSUS2010POP, ESTIMATESBASE2010, POPESTIMATE2010, 
                  POPESTIMATE2011, POPESTIMATE2012, POPESTIMATE2013, POPESTIMATE2014
FROM     [SUB-EST2014_ALL]
WHERE  (STATE = '4') AND (COUNTY = '13')
```

I only want the results from the second query to show. If both results show up there will be a lot of duplication.

I am not a novice at SQL queries but I am by no means an expert. This is well above my level of knowledge. Can anyone help me get this setup?

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is [INNER JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your first query only ever returns 1 row then you could select STATE and COUNTRY into variables then use those in the second query.  If it returns more than 1 row then join the two result sets...

```
SELECT Q2.*
FROM
(
  SELECT STATE, COUNTY
  FROM [SUB-EST2014_ALL]
  WHERE (SUMLEV = '50') AND (CENSUS2010POP > 1000000) AND (CENSUS2010POP < 100000000)
) Q1

INNER JOIN

(
  SELECT SUMLEV, STATE, COUNTY, PLACE, COUSUB, CONCIT, PRIMGEO_FLAG, FUNCSTAT, NAME, STNAME, CENSUS2010POP, ESTIMATESBASE2010, POPESTIMATE2010, 
              POPESTIMATE2011, POPESTIMATE2012, POPESTIMATE2013, POPESTIMATE2014
  FROM [SUB-EST2014_ALL]
) Q2 ON Q1.STATE = Q2.STATE AND Q1.COUNTRY = Q2.COUNTRY
```

Comment: the first query does return more than 1 row so the inner join is what i needed. this works perfect. thanks for the help.